# How to prove that the following conclusion is true?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs, combinatorial-game-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Consider a set $\mathcal{X}$ with $m$ numbers, and take out $a, b, c, d$ numbers respectively.

The number of combinations of $a$ number taken from $\mathcal{X}$ is recorded as $C_{m}^{a}$.

The number of combinations of $b$ number taken from $\mathcal{X}$ is recorded as $C_{m}^{b}$.

The number of combinations of $c$ number taken from $\mathcal{X}$ is recorded as $C_{m}^{c}$.

The number of combinations of $d$ number taken from $\mathcal{X}$ is recorded as $C_{m}^{d}$.

If $a+b=c+d$ and $c<b<a<d$, how to prove that $C_{m}^{a}C_{m}^{b}>C_{m}^{c}C_{m}^{d}$?

Comment: The answer is to short . It can be elaborated to make it more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for your correction, I have modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Too long for a comment.**

Let's just try an example and see if it is illuminating.

Suppose $m = 12$, and that $c<b<a<d$ is, respectively, $2<3<7<8$.

So, $a=7$, $b=3$, $c=2$, $d=8$, and (as desired) $a+b=10=c+d$.

Written out combinatorially, the desired inequality to prove is:

$$\frac{12!}{7!5!} \frac{12!}{3!9!} > \frac{12!}{2!10!}\frac{12!}{4!8!}$$

The numerators are the same, so dividing both sides by $12!12!$ and then cross multiplying yields the equivalent inequality:

$$(4!8!)(2!10!) > (5!7!)(3!9!)$$

We can see this last inequality will hold by examining each of the parenthetical terms:

$4!8! > 5!7!$ because the extra term on $8!$ is an $8$, which is larger than the extra term from $5!$, which is a $5$.

If you write out a couple more examples, then perhaps you can see how this can be phrased into more general language.

Comment: Thank you sir for your guidance，I have tried some simple examples so far, but I still haven’t written a more general and rigorous proof language.

Comment: Sir, can you take a look at the issue I mentioned yesterday? I have been troubled for a long time and there is no suitable proof.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839637/how-to-prove-the-conclusion-of-the-product-problem-in-combination

Comment: @Kristy Try some numerical examples by hand. But also, it appears from your link that you have posted the same question twice. This is frowned upon on MSE and will almost certainly lead to closure(s).